# MVC Controller(s) with RESTful API(s), multiple Models and shared Views

Tags: php, rest, design-patterns, model-view-controller, laravel

**Foreword:** The following text is of decent size, because I tried to maximize the value to other readers with similar, fundamental and conceptual questions.

---

### Introduction

Currently I am developing an web-based event management tool, which uses the Laravel MVC framework to maintain a proper application structure and ease development.

The goals targeted with the application are to

- provide a efficient way to create (respectively CRUD) events
- invite registered users to those events
- allow users to confirm their participation on previously created events

Following the MVC-Pattern, I created

- a Model named `Event`
- a `EventController`
- multiple views

  - a static `event` view, displaying already existing events
  - a form view for creation and editing named `eventForm`
  - `eventIndex`,  a list of all events

Up to this point, everything seemed to be relatively straight-forward, but I ran into design problems, when I tried to implement further functionality to allow users to confirm their participation on specific events.

#### Further Details

For further clarification, each `Event` has a number of attributes (some omitted):

- Title
- Description
- Multiple `EventDate`s, consisting out of this attributes:

  - Title
  - A timespan (for example 09-20-2013 09:00 AM to 09-20-2013 05:00 PM)

The aforementioned `EventDate` is also a model with an associated database table.

Distinguished by the account a user is logged in with, I made a boolean variable `$admin` available to all views and controllers, which is used to alter the view `event` in the following way:

- **$admin = true:** The view is a static page, showing the `Event`s attributes and `EventDate`s in a table
- **$admin = false:** In addition, the view has a hidden form and buttons for each `EventDate` table row, allowing the users to confirm or decline their participation on each of the `EventDate`s

Using a variable and `@if...@endif`-blocks to alter the view seems acceptable to me, as, despite of the hidden form, the differences between *User-Mode* and *Admin-Mode* are quite small.

### The Problem

Now, the problem I am stuck at, is the following:

*Who is responsible for processing the POSTed data of the User-Mode hidden form?*

At first, here a few facts to the current development state:

- The `Event` controller currently offers the following functions:

  ```
  /* CRUD functions */
  public function CreateEvent()
  public function ShowEvent($id)
  public function UpdateEvent($id)
  public function DeleteEvent($id)
  /* Form display helpers */
  public function NewEvent()
  public function EditEvent()
  ```
- The `EventDate` Model is separate from the `Event` Model, as a `Event` has multiple `EventDate`s
- Confirmations are stored per user and `EventDate` in another separate table bound to the `EventDateConfirmation` model

### Solution approaches

These are the options I have thougth of:

1. The `EventController`, which must be extended with methods like `CreateEventDateConfirmation()` and so on, leading to multiple CRUD methods, which not even belong to this controller, as they are not directly regarded to the `Event` model and no change at all happens in the `events` table
2. In a separate `EventDateConfirmationController`, only responsible for getting and setting the `EventDateConfirmation` model data, with two usage possibilities:

   - Calling the `EventDateConfirmationControler` methods from the `EventController` by using the somewhat clunky

     ```
     Controller::resolve(DEFAULT_BUNDLE,'EventDateConfirmationController')->CreateConfirmation($params);
     ```
   - Setting the route which responds to the hidden form POST-request to the corresponding `EventDateConfirmationController` action directly

   The first possibility has the disadvantage of calling an external controller in a unpleasant way which seems wrong to me, the second is not practicable when the form also contains data which belong directly to a event and therefore must be handled by the `Event` controller
3. **??**

In my opinion, neither #1 nor #2 are good solutions to the problem, as they seem to be hack-ish and do not fit very well in the MVC-pattern.

**What alternatives are available, which would be a clean solution to this problem?**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your model is anemic. Hell, you actually do not have a model layer, instead you have a collection of active record objects, that you refer to as "models". This is why you see the domain business logic leaking in the controllers (and presentation layer in general). The solution would be - ditch the Rails-like architecture and try implementing MVC.

Comment: After looking at your problem , I feel you have not done the system design properly . Basically you have not discovered the entities of your application before starting to code . if you have done that I am 100 % sure you wouldnt have endded up with the mess , Next time please make sure you draw the UML's before starting to code .

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara going all-UML usually is an overkill. Especially for something in small-to-medium scale of project like this one. Usually just making a [domain model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model) with diagram that's vaguely resembling "class diagram" is enough.

Comment: @tereško class diagram is also an UML I meant some UML has to be made before starting to code

Comment: I usually just end up making a [mind map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_map) .. because I am lazy.

Comment: Maybe i can recommend you a resource oriented solution? Using resources and resourceRepositories? Currently we are creating a REST agnostic framework: https://github.com/yunait/level3, this can you give some hints. (We use Silex very similar to Laravel4)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to do #2 and make it a little less hackish but still not have to change much from before. Otherwise I think #1 is not a good choice.

Realistically what I would do if I were in your circumstance is create the EventDateConfirmationController and in the User-Mode view, make it a separate form that is asynchronous ajax. Either submit the form when the user clicks [assuming] the checkbox that he/she is going, or on when they submit the other form.

I definitely feel like javascript can help you keep your code consistent and still MVC like.